# ctags error "format error in tags file"

Tags: ctags, cscope

I work on c code base in Linux. I use perforce as source code repository. I had been using ctags and it was working fine. But recently when press ctrl ] in some symbol then I get below error. I removed tags file and recreated the tags file but the problem didn't solve. Any idea on how to resolve this issue?
E431: Format error in tags file "tags"
Before byte 53035586

Answer (score 3):

If you are just using the ctags -R then try specifying the c language in the command like below. I had the same problem and when I specified the c language while generating the tags, the problem got resolved.

- ctags -R --languages=C

Answer (score 0):

There may be tags with large names in your repo. If you can live without those included in your ctags file, you can avoid this error and use rest of the ctags.

To avoid the files/folders, use this syntax

**ctags -R -V --exclude=@/path/to/ctags_ignore_file ./ **

ctags_ignore_file has the list of Folders to be excluded. You can use wildcard entries too.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; add `export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim` to `~/.bashrc` and close your terminal window.

In my case, setting **vim** as the default editor for **cscope** fixed the issue:

```
echo "export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim" >> ~/.bashrc # Append to .bashrc
source ~/.bashrc # Load .bashrc into the current shell
```

After this, you may also use the following commands in your project directory for a quick reconfiguration of **cscope** and **ctags**:

```
ctags -R 
cscope -R
```